# Pass the typed text to the remote request with typeahead bloodhound

Tags: typeahead.js, twitter-typeahead, bloodhound

I've seem [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21821658/typeahead-bloodhound-post-request) [topics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29631662/pass-a-parameter-into-bloodhound-from-typeahead) about [the same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25785344/typeahead-bootstrap3-how-to-pass-a-parameter-into-remote), but all of them seem to be using the `replace` option.

This option [doesn't seem to exist anymore in the current bloodhound](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/bloodhound.md#options).

Right now I have the following which isn't showing any result at all:

```
var url = 'http://demo.com';

var suggestions = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    prefetch: [],
    remote: {
        url: url + '/equipment/getSuggestions/%QUERY'
    }
});


$('#equipment-id-input').typeahead({
    highlight: true,
    minLength: 3,
    source: suggestions
});
```

I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong as no errors are shown. 
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21533204/1081396).

Although I do not understand what does the function `ttAdapter` in:

```
$('.typeahead').typeahead(null, {
    displayKey: 'value',
    source: movies.ttAdapter()
});
```